# Resistance band too tight on palm

Tags: strength, resistance-cord

I have a resistance band and I'm finding that it gets too tight on my palm when I pull. It gets wrinkled up and hurts my palm.

How do I mitigate this?

Comment: The simplest way would just be to buy padded workout gloves! Also You can by the single resistance bands that aren't loops and attach rubber d handles to one end of them(bought in stores for that purpose). You can still make it a band by using a clip and attaching one end to another.

Comment: You may want to replace the bands with ones that use a solid handle.

Answer (score 1):

Loop the band on anything resembling a handle/dumbell.

Here's some examples.

[image]

[image]

[image]

But remember that looping a band increases the tension.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I almost feel scammed. I can barely use it without my palms getting hurt

Comment: I am  wrapping it with a cloth - it makes it better to hold

Comment: What about padded workout gloves, those are a cheap and easy solution?